# React to audio being connected & disconnected to an airplay device

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, airplay

I'm looking for a way to immediately react to the audio output being connected and disconnected to an airplay device.
There are `UIScreen.didConnectNotification` and `UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification` but they will only notify when mirroring is activated in control center.

I want to highlight the airplay icon on screen while output is being routed to another device.

Answer (score 0):

And just when you're posting on StackOverflow you find the solution.

Register to  `MPVolumeViewWirelessRouteActiveDidChange`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(checkForAirplayRouting),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name.MPVolumeViewWirelessRouteActiveDidChange,
                                       object: nil)

let volumeView: MPVolumeView!

@objc func checkForAirplayRouting() {
   //print(#function)
   volumeView.tintColor = volumeView.isWirelessRouteActive ? UIColor.orange : UIColor.white
}
```

This will update when the user selects an airplay device in the MPVolumeView